# Lookup complexity in B-trees [Database]

Tags: search-trees, databases, balanced-search-trees

Given that:

```
B = n/R blocks in the file
2d index records per block (blocking factor): 2d > R
an extra block access from the index to the datafile
```

I am not able to wrap my head around as why the lookup would incur an cost[number of block accesses] of
less than or equal to

```
2 + log(base to d) (n/2)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just do your (home-)work for you; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]? You may also want to check out our [reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599/).

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, figured it out. One access would be required to find the root of B-tree. And then Logd(n/2) access to find the correct leaf containing the right key. And then another another block access to reach the requested data for the given key.